# How to select rows that meet multiple criteria from a column (mismatch)?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro using VBA in excel to copy the rows based on column A that does not appear in column B, to a new sheet. For example, on the following table, only copy the rows with column A that is 3,4, 5, and 6 to a new sheet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The table looks like below.

> ```
> Column A ColumnB
> 1        1 
> 1        2 
> 1        7 
> 2        -
> 2        -
> 3        -
> 3        -
> 4        -
> 5        -
> 5        -
> 6        -
> 7        -
> ```

Comment: Which exact part of that are you having a problem with?  You should be able to use `Application.Match()` to find out if a specific value exists in ColB.

Comment: Refer the link - http://superuser.com/questions/81498/find-items-in-one-column-that-are-not-in-another-column

Comment: You cannot use the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to filter for `<>` on more than two criteria.

However, you CAN autofilter on those criteria first (in sequence) and populate a dictionary of keys to be used in a subsequent autofilter operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sorter()
Dim find1 As Object, find2 As Object
Dim row1 As Integer, row2 As Integer
Dim myWB As Workbook

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
row1 = 1
row2 = 1

Do
    Set find1 = myWB.Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Find(What:=myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(row1, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If find1 Is Nothing Then
        Set find2 = myWB.Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Find(What:=myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(row1, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If find2 Is Nothing Then
            myWB.Sheets(2).Cells(row2, 1).Value = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(row1, 1).Value
            row2 = row2 + 1
        End If
    End If
row1 = row1 + 1
Loop Until myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(row1, 1).Value = ""

End Sub
```

just make sure you dont put blanks in first column :)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick reply! Second, there are two issues: 1) in column A, there are 2 rows with "3" and 2 rows with "5". But in sheet2, there is one row with "3" and one row with "5"; 2) I need to copy the whole row to a new sheet, I guess I can make changes like this: myWB.Sheets(2).Rows(row2).Value = myWB.Sheets(1).Rows(row1).Value